# How to color an SVG image drawn with coordinates?

Tags: css, html, svg, path

As part of a programming assignment, I am trying to give color to all European countries. 
I found the coordinates of these countries from the following wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-World6.svg).

Let's say, for example, that I want to color Northern Ireland. The coordinates are given here:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="landxx gb eu" d="M 1260.508,337.032 C 1261.121,336.062 1262.494,336.081 1263.388,335.52 1263.057,335.277 1262.743,335.012 1262.448,334.727 1264.3,335.304 1265.011,333.238 1265.893,332.227 1266.732,331.266 1268.474,332.53 1268.718,330.767 1270.35,331.522 1272.386,329.639 1274.016,330.766 1274.677,331.222 1275.068,332.288 1275.375,332.975 1275.319,332.851 1276.594,334.325 1276.56,334.063 1276.597,334.341 1275.171,335.037 1274.978,335.231 1275.478,335.181 1276.972,334.543 1277.301,335.202 1277.635,335.87 1278.28,337.23 1277.138,337.536 1277.316,336.828 1277.055,335.884 1276.128,336.096 1276.687,336.427 1276.615,337.009 1276.268,337.464 1276.561,337.31 1276.811,337.331 1277.018,337.527 1277.091,338.02 1275.965,338.658 1275.586,338.698 1274.608,338.801 1274.61,340.437 1273.42,340.084 1272.419,339.787 1272.235,339.475 1271.382,340.035 1270.657,340.511 1269.467,340.023 1269.788,339.049 1269.388,339.07 1266.639,336.003 1266.454,337.971 1266.126,341.45 1261.861,338.159 1260.508,337.032" id="path2690"/>
```

I'd like to colour this country in a separate CSS file. I though I could do this by accessing the id of the country in the CSS file:

```
#path2690 {
    fill: green;
}
```

It is not working, however. What is going wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Any jsfiddle available ?

Comment: How are you linking your SVG to the css file? How are you using the SVG file as a standalone image or embedding it into an html document, if so how are you embedding it?

Comment: @Midhun and Robert Longson here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xG8qs/

Comment: The file really isn't valid. The first path has been replaced by an `<svg>` tag and many of the countries aren't pased in properly so the tags are not closed. That's probably why it doesn't work. Try cutting down the file to 1 country, validating it using the w3c validator (http://validator.w3.org/) and see if you can get that to work.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok I edited and cut the file down to 1 country. This is the new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xG8qs/1/ . Do you know why it does not work now? I did validate the code at w3c, but I can't fix the errors they gave me over there (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. Firstly you can't display a raw SVG `<path>` in an html file it has to be wrapped in a `<svg>` element.

Once you do that, it displays but the country is so small you can't see it no matter what colour it is even though the colouring actually works. If you give the `<svg>` element a viewBox of `viewBox="1415 390 30 30"` [you can then see it](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/xG8qs/3/) and see that adjusting the colour in CSS changes it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one final question though. I'd like to put multiple countries on their "right" position on a map. Do you know how to do this as well?

Comment: As far as I saw they were at their "right" position so ask another question and give details of the problem.